# RF link wireless trigger (press/hold) with no mcu

Tags: rf, wireless

i have a talking birthday card to trigger from distance of 20-100m (line of sight).
what would be the easiest way to send press/release (and hold) commands?

i expect a false positive here and there.
this project is for a layman workshop, so i want to keep it simple
was looking at 315Mhz link tx/rx kits. selling for a few $ on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on exactly what information you need to send to the card (e.g. simple pulse, or a few bytes, or..) you could do this a few ways.

If you have one lying around, hacking a wireless alarm doorbell / garage opener or similar might be an easy option. Press, release and hold may not be part of the standard setup though.

The tx/rx eBay modules you mention should be fine for this, you can also get wireless relay/switching kits that are designed for this type of simple application (e.g. press button, toggle switch or logic output) Some have a transparent mode where they just send exactly what is input, so a switch and flip-flop might do what you are asking for.

If it's line of sight and you can lower the distance requirement a bit, an IR (infra-red) tx/rx might be the way to go.

If you give a few more details on exactly what you want to send (e.g. does the switch have to latch, or just do exactly what the button at the transmitting side does?), a more specific answer can be given.

Comment: the switch should dupliacte the input, no latch.   i think your answer covers all bases. i think i will try the rf link method.